# Perforce Java API Line-Ending Style

Tags: java, perforce

My program needs to read a list of files from a Perforce repository using the Java API provided by Perforce. This program uses a shared read-only login, and fetches files without using a client workspace.

This all works fine, however the problem I have is that the files always appear to be checked out with \r\n line endings. I have tried various naughty hacks (e.g. setting the System property line.separator to \n), but these don't work. I have noticed that the line-ending style in the p4v client is set on the workspace. Am I required to have a workspace to set the line-ending style?

Unfortunately, whilst there are a few files which never change, and I can commit those as binary, the other files I retrieve cannot be committed as binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the line ends of local files are determined by the client (aka workspace) setting when calling "sync".
If you fetch files without syncing and without a client then you have to "print" them.
In that case you would have to do the line end translations yourself.

Perhaps you can sync the files by creating a temporary client. 
[Here's an example](https://github.com/fdrueke/ivyp4/blob/master/src/com/orga/ivy/plugins/p4resolver/P4PublishTransaction.java) for that (look at method P4PublishTransaction).